# Line segment detection QGis orfeo toolbox

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I would like to extract linear features from a high resolution DEM.

I have found that a "line segment detection" tool exists in the Orfeo toolbox in QGis.

I could not find easy to understand, comprehensive documentation with examples on how to use this tool.

I tried to run the tool, initially I got an error message which referred to an invalid operand type.

Then I downloaded an OTB folder for windows, tried to re-run the tool but now I get this error message: "OTB folder is not configured. Please configure it before running OTB algorithms".

Anyone can help?

Comment: From the menubar, go to: `Processing > Options... > Providers > Orfeo Toolbox`, make sure it's enabled and try setting the applications folder to the OTB folder you downloaded.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I did it. Now it gives me yet a different error.  'otbcli.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Couldn't find much information regarding this issue except for this:[Login Register Unable to install OTB qgis plugin properly](http://otb-users.37221.n3.nabble.com/Unable-to-install-OTB-qgis-plugin-properly-td4029334.html). A possible workaround, it seems, is to install the **standalone QGIS 2.8**.

Answer (score 1):

can you try first to use the OTB application outside QGIS and see how it works?

You can use a standalone archive which contains GUI for the applications (mapla.exe).

Check OTB download page:

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/